Coherence deleting too much in gmsh gui
I have a 3d model of some intersecting wires in a volume of gas that I am trying to mesh so I can get the electric field for this configuration from elmer for detector physics simulations. The wires and gas are two separate models because they are two separate bodies for the purposes of the FEM software.
3d model of wires  by themselves
3d model of the gas volume by itself
wires and gas together
When I save this as a step file and mesh it in gmsh without doing anything else, it creates overlapping surfaces where the wires meet the gas. To solve this I used the coherence option in GMSH GUI, which usually just collapses coplanar surfaces onto each other and fixes this, but instead it is deleting all the overlapping points and surfaces and not just one set of them. Here is what it looks like in GMSH gui before and after using coherence:
step file in gmsh before coherence
after coherence
I am not sure how to resolve this. I want to mesh these bodies such that they share a single surface where they meet.
I read that coherence is a shortcut for the fragments command but I cannot seem to select the right combination of things in the GUI to use this correctly, so I am somewhat at a dead end.
